# Hbase shell: value is cut

Tags: hbase

I've got a hbase table named 'mytable' with only one column family 'default' and only one qualifier 'details'.

Now I do this query:

```
get 'mytable', 'test'
```

And the value of the result is cut. It should be a number (long):

```
COLUMN                      CELL                                                                           
default:details            timestamp=1337007859494, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xDFH                   
1 row(s) in 0.0360 seconds
```

Why do I only see the first seven bytes? How can I see the full value?

If I ask for something with a small value, it works. But big values are incomplete.

Comment: How are you inserting the values?

Comment: The values are inserted by a Map Reduce job written in Java.

Comment: Can you try making the MR job print the value just before inserting, just to ensure that the wrong values are not getting inserted. Also, try reading the values using a java file, to ensure this is not a problem with the jruby shell.

Comment: OK, I did so. See the first answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All 8 bytes of your long are in that string:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xDFH
```

Easier to see this way:

```
\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \xDF H
```

The first 6 bytes are 0 (hex \x00), the next one is 223 (hex \xDF) and the last is ASCII H (\x48), this makes your long in decimal 57,160. HBase's values are just character arrays and not type aware so the shell escapes as hex all bytes that are not printable ASCII and leaves alone ones that are, not always the clearest.

Comment: How did you come to 57,160 from the previous?

Comment: The number he has is 0xDF48, which when translated into decimal is 57160:  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=0xdf48+in+decimal

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I wrote a little Java which tells me the value. This works. Stupid hbase shell.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;


public class HBaseGet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if(args.length < 4) {
        throw new IOException("Parameters: table rowid columnFamily qualifier");
    }

    assert args.length >= 4;

    String tablename = args[0];
    byte[] rowid = Bytes.toBytes(args[1]);
    byte[] family = Bytes.toBytes(args[2]);
    byte[] qualifier = Bytes.toBytes(args[3]);

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HTable table = new HTable(config, tablename);

    Get get = new Get(rowid);
    Result result = table.get(get);

    if (result != null) {
        byte[] value = result.getValue(family, qualifier);
        String valueStr = Bytes.toString(value);

        // convert bytes to long
        long valueLong = 0L;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
        {
            valueLong = (valueLong << 8) + (value[i] & 0xff);
        }

        System.out.println("================");
        System.out.println("String: "+valueStr);
        System.out.println("Long: "+valueLong);
        System.out.println("================");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I like cftarnas' answer because it really answers my question. Coding this script is no beautiful solution.

Comment: Makes sense, it answers the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the MR job print the value just before inserting, just to ensure that the wrong values are not getting inserted.

Also try reading the values using a java file, to ensure this is not a problem with the jruby shell.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is:

```
get 'mytable', 'test', {COLUMN => 'default:details:toLong'}
```

The `Long` :) version:

If you type `help 'get'` in HBase's shell, you'll find this:

```
Besides the default 'toStringBinary' format, 'get' also supports custom formatting by
column.  A user can define a FORMATTER by adding it to the column name in the get
specification.  The FORMATTER can be stipulated: 

 1. either as a org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes method name (e.g, toInt, toString)
 2. or as a custom class followed by method name: e.g. 'c(MyFormatterClass).format'.

Example formatting cf:qualifier1 and cf:qualifier2 both as Integers: 
  hbase> get 't1', 'r1' {COLUMN => ['cf:qualifier1:toInt',
    'cf:qualifier2:c(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes).toInt'] }
```