# Making sense of encoded hbase values

Tags: binary, hex, hbase

I'm currently investigating a bug where data is being corrupted and we're unsure in which component this is happening. I'm attempting to read the values out of Hbase but can make no sense of them because the encoding. I was told it's 'binary encoded hex' (whatever that means). **Does anyone know how to decode these values?** Any solution would be appreciated; whether it be some utility I can download or a step by step manual process. Below are some sample rows from my hbase scan.

`column=m:----_daily_count, timestamp=1345766400000, value=\x00\x00\x00\x01`
`column=a:utc_offset, timestamp=1346025600000, value=\xFF\xFF\x9D\x90`
`column=m:----_daily_count, timestamp=1344816000000, value=\x00\x00\x00\x03`

---- is replacing the names of data types which potentially reveal information about unreleased products.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps but HBase doesn't understand types and essentially stores everything as a sequence of bytes. Its pretty easy to go from the hex encoding to the actual byte value:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x01
```

is the byte sequence:

```
0 0 0 1
```

If I had to guess, those values are supposed to be longs so the above would just be 1L.

You can use the java API (specificaly, the org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes class) to convert the byte sequences to actual types in java but to make any sense of it, you'll need to know the types that they were serialized from. Also, this assumes that whatever is writing the data is also written in java and/or has the same endianess.

If you know ruby, you can also use the unpack() method of the string class which understands those byte sequences but you'll still need to know the type/endianess in order to do so and if its not a primitive, it probably won't work.

Comment: That's a start but I could still use a little bit of clarification. Those values are in fact longs, so the first one would just be 1? You said it's a byte sequence but if it's 4 different bytes for example `4 3 3 1` how does that translate to an actual integer? Also some of these values have non hex characters like U or Q how do those translate to bytes?

Comment: I think you really need to understand what is writing them to know how to interpret them properly

Comment: Cftarnas' answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586368/hbase-shell-value-is-cutted) helps clarify this.